# 5 yr residence card: does it let me travel without my husband?

Tags: visas, uk, regulations, paperwork, spouses

I am Australian, married to an EU national, and have just been issued with a 5 yr residence card. I want to travel to Malta with a friend. My husband and I run an import business in the UK and my husband travels a lot to China. He stays there for 3 to 4 months at a time sorting product and branding etc.

Am I free to travel and come back to the UK without him? Will they question this at the airport? I'm worried they might class him as not living here in UK, as he is kind of living in china. I worry that they won't let me back in the UK to run our business.Or do they not question this at all when I go through customs?

Comment: I've edited the best I can but the important piece of information - who issued the residence card? Could you edit that into the question please?

Comment: You added so much irrelevant information. The only that matters is: what passport(s) do you have, which country issued card and where do you want to go. Please state this clearly.

Comment: The status of your husband is completely irrelevant. And it doesn't matter if you travel alone or together for you.

Comment: The status of her COULD be relevant because visa rules for people married to EU nationals could be different.

Comment: @Andrey Under EU law, the husband's status is very important, traveling together also matters in some situations. If the husband is not a UK resident and the OP is not traveling with him, she would be treated as a regular visitor and, depending on her own nationality, might require a costly visa or even be denied the right to enter. If he was not a resident but he was traveling with her, she might need a visa but it should be free. If the husband is a UK resident, she is *entitled* to have the right to reside there under EU law (which seems to be the case here).

Comment: @Annoyed how it can be relevant if she has residence card? It means that she is legal resident of the UK and has right to enter until card is expired or her family status changes.

Comment: @Andrey That's precisely one of the situations alluded to in my comment. The point is that there are many other situations in which it's relevant so it's entirely reasonable to provide this information.

Comment: @Annoyed does it really matter if her husband is UK resident or not, if she has the residence card?

Comment: @Andrey If she has a UK residence card as the spouse of a EU/EEA citizen then it would be because her husband is a resident… If she has another UK residence card then I presume that none of this matters (this would not depend on EU law and I am not particularly familiar wit UK law). But, again, my main point is that it matters in many situations, it's just not true that this is completely irrelevant and that the only things that matter are the passport, country of residence and destination.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you hold an Australian passport which you can use that to travel to Malta without any problem as long as it's not more than 90 days. Now the question is to go back to the UK. One thing that I know from my friend who used to be in the same position as you (he married to an English girl) is that if the immigration officer didn't think your marriage is a sham. They wouldn't ask where your husband is. Or they might ask how did you get the residence card. And as long as you can provide them with an honest answer they can at least ask questions (I'm not saying they cannot reject your entry). But it's unlikely that if you're husband is outside the country and you'll be rejected your entry. So, they might ask what're you doing in the UK and how long. You can just give them an honest answer.

And as you're Australian you can come to the UK with your Australian passport anyway. So, I don't see any problem for you to travel to Malta and back to the UK.

One thing to note that if you want to apply for a British passport you should not stay outside the UK longer than 180 days in 5 years.